# Super elastic collision in Blender-a simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, blend-files, collision

Can someone write for me a `.blend` file (i.e. a MWE) which would be a super-elastic collision either in 1D or in 2D or finally 3D of 2 elastic balls with customizable $Q$ as in this equation $$K+Q=K'$$ where $K$ is a kinetic energy before and $K'$ a kinetic energy afterwords with $Q>(=,<) 0$?
Choose whatever you think is easiest and try to create a MWE. I think this is possible as I have seen **falling** object from top to bottom in Blender.